sqflite error "cannot commit - no transaction is active" fires only in release mode on iOS
The error
flutter: error DatabaseException(Error Domain=SqfliteDarwinDatabase Code=1 "cannot commit - no transaction is active" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=cannot commit - no transaction is active}) sql 'COMMIT' args [] during open, closing...
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(Error Domain=SqfliteDarwinDatabase Code=1 "cannot commit - no transaction is active" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=cannot commit - no transaction is active}) sql 'COMMIT' args []

reproducec only in release mode on iOS on app laucng. The code is:
Future<Database> getDBInstance({BuildContext? context}) async {
  debugPrint('getting db instance');
  if (database == null) {
    debugPrint('db is null');
    Database db;
    if (Platform.isWindows) {
      sqfliteFfiInit();
      var databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
      db = await databaseFactory.openDatabase("cashway.db",
          options: OpenDatabaseOptions(
              version: 1, onCreate: onCreate, onUpgrade: onUpgrade));
    } else {
      String databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
      String dbPath = join(databasesPath, 'cashway.db');
      //the last printed output
      debugPrint('opening db');
      db = await openDatabase(dbPath,
          version: 1, onCreate: onCreate, onUpgrade: onUpgrade);
    }
    database = db;
    return db;
  } else {
    Database db = database!;
    return db;
  }
}

void onCreate(Database database, int version) async {
  debugPrint('on create');
  for (MigrationCallback callback in migrations) {
    debugPrint('doin migration');
    await callback(database);
  }
  resetDatabase();
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await getDBInstance();

  AppProvider appProvider = await AppProvider.getInstance();

  runApp(MultiProvider(
      providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => appProvider)],
      child: const App()));
}

The getDBInstance is called in different places but I believe it's not the root of the problem since it fires only in release mode on iOS. But probably I'm wrong. The app itself hangs on black screen but asks for permissions for camera.
UPD
Future<void> resetDatabase(database) async {
  debugPrint('resetting');
  database.delete("payments", where: "id>0");
  database.delete("accounts", where: "id>0");
  database.delete("categories", where: "id>0");
  debugPrint('removed all entries');

  await database.insert("accounts", {
    "name": "Наличные",
    "icon": Icons.wallet.codePoint,
    "color": Colors.teal.value,
    "isDefault": 1
  });


Somewhere, you are writing to the database and ending a transaction that was not started.  Would you POST that code, and a full stacktrace?

reproducec only in release mode on iOS on app laucng.   Uninstall your debug app before installing the release build!

What you can try first:

Create the parent folder of the database before opening the database, it sometimes does not exist yet
Check that in your migration callbacks - or anything that could happen during onCreate and onUpdate -, all db calls are properly awaited
Show some sql logs to check that indeed everything happens in the proper order - quick way. databaseFactory = databaseFactory.debugQuickLoggerWrapper(); - see here

One question to be sure

I'm not sure what resetDatabase do. I assume it does not access the database (edited: that was the issue!)


The probleb was in resetDatabase. It had line database = await getDBInstance. I passed the "database" argument to the method instead of it and it helped. Thank you for your answer, but it would be great if you'd update the answer with details about this update. Marked your answer as correct because your last question got me to check out the resetDatabase method
